# What are the differences between instantiating a new class and getting that component from a game object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I want to reference a script which is attached to a different game object, I usually do

```
ThatClass tc;
GameObject tc;

void Start(){
    tc = tc.GetComponent<ThatClass>();
}
```

but what about this way ?

```
ThatClass tc = new ThatClass();
```

What are the differences between these ways ?

Comment: One is attached to a `GameObject` and the other isn't?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html

Comment: Yes, but for example, x gameobject has Class class attached to it and y gameobject has a script which instantiates the Class script inside of it. If y gameobject changes a value of Class class, would the value also change on the script attached to x gameobject ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get `null` if cout `GameObject` doesn't have a attached object:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html

Answer (score 0):

Because unity components exits partially in the non-managed part of Unity, you are not allowed to access the explicit constructor for classes that derive from MonoBehaviour, you need to use the GetCopomonent/AddComponent methods provided by the GameObject